# Android disable or fix tab scrolling when using Hebrew indicator

Tags: android, tabs, scroll, android-tabhost, hebrew

I have a problem with my tabHost and tabs... when I try them out on Android 2.2 or lower it works just fine. However on android 3.0 or higher there is a problem when I try to use Hebrew string indicator for a tab. the app "thinks" the text is too long, and therefor it is using the scroll/fade animation.. (while English string are working just fine)..

As you can see in the picture below, when I try an English text indicator, even if it is abit long, it works fine. When I enter a Hebrew text indicator (even if its only 2 letters long) the system asssumes that the text is too long..

How can I disable or fix it?

A screen shot of the problem:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/210/tabsproblem.jpg/

Comment: Are you using custom layout for each tab or the built-in one and you just setText to it?

Comment: Its just the default, all i used was spec.setindicator("title")

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that customized tabs will do the work just fine, though I'm still not sure why the problem occurs when using Hebrew tab titles. 
So my recommandation is to customize the tab layout by your selves :)